# Difference between lambda expression and method group

Tags: c#, lambda, method-group

What's the difference between

```
Class1.Method1<Guid, BECustomer>("cId", Facade.Customers.GetSingle);
```

and

```
Class1.Method1<Guid, BECustomer>("cId", x => Facade.Customers.GetSingle(x));
```

?

Resharper suggests to use the first expression.

Comment: In C# there's no semantic difference. In Java, a similar type of thing results in different bindings of 'this'! I get bit by this all of the time...

Answer (score 25, accepted):

There is no difference in regards to the result. However, the second one creates an additional redirection: The code will first call your anonymous method the takes one parameter named `x` and that in turn calls `Facade.Customers.GetSingle` with that parameter. This redirection has no benefit at all, that's why ReSharper tells you to use the first alternative.

Comment: That's correct, I think this is just syntactic sugar for lambdas with only one parameter.

Comment: @Vladislav: What do you mean? The first version is not syntactic sugar for the second one. The first one passes the "function pointer" of the `GetSingle` method, whereas the second one passes the "function pointer" of the anonymous method.

Comment: It's not restricted to single-parameter lambdas - method groups will work for any matching delegate signature.

Comment: There's a difference with respect to closure. Suppose `Facade.Customers` changes as time goes by. Then the first one (method group from named method) will keep the original `Customers`, whereas the second one (anonymous function from lambda) will reflect the new `Customers` (`Customers` is re-evaluated by the anonymous function). So in the second one, evaluation is "deferred". If this is hard to understand, try out this code: `string test = "12345"; Func<string, bool> f = test.Contains; Func<string, bool> g = x => test.Contains(x); test = "changed!"; bool a = f("34"); bool b = g("34");`.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen: Correct. I didn't include it in this answer because `Facade.Customers` looked pretty static to me. I explained the difference in more detail in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13603795/using-delegates-in-c-sharp/13603863#13603863). Thanks.

Comment: For an example where only method group conversion (not lambda) is allowed, here is an example with a `ref` parameter. Namely the code `static void M1(ref string s)
    {
      Func<string, bool> f1 = s.Contains; /* OK */
    }` is fine; however the code `static void M2(ref string s)
    {
      Func<string, bool> f2 = x => s.Contains(x); /* Compile-time error, cannot close over 'ref' parameter */
    }` is illegal.

Comment: On the other hand, an example where only lambda (not method group) is allowed can be made when the "target" is a nullable type. These have special boxing conversions (as is well known) which leads to funny examples here. For example: `int? a = 42; Func<int> f1 = a.GetValueOrDefault;/* interestingly not allowed */ Func<int> f2 = () => a.GetValueOrDefault();/* fine of course */`. Even when both are allowed (for methods inherited by `Nullable<>` from its base classes), they may behave differently when the "target" `HasValue` is false. Example: `int? a = null; Func<string> g = a.ToString;`

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen I thought I knew about method group syntax until I surprised myself by finding out the IL generated for them differs from the "hand-rolled" lambda call, and upon searching for why, find this answer and your's and Daniel's comment. TIL... :-)

Answer (score 16):

Behind the scenes, the compiler generates a lot more code if you use the lambda expression. With the method group, it just makes a new delegate pointing to that method:

```
L_0001: ldstr "cId"
L_0006: ldnull 
L_0007: ldftn void Facade/Customers::GetSingle(valuetype [mscorlib]System.Guid)
L_000d: newobj instance void [mscorlib]System.Action`1<valuetype [mscorlib]System.Guid>::.ctor(object, native int)
L_0012: call void Class1::Method1<valuetype [mscorlib]System.Guid, class BECustomer>(string, class [mscorlib]System.Action`1<!!0>)
```

With the lambda expression, an anonymous method is created on the class (`<Test>b__0` on L_0025) and the delegate references that instead:

```
L_0018: ldstr "cId"
L_001d: ldsfld class [mscorlib]System.Action`1<valuetype [mscorlib]System.Guid> Class1::CS$<>9__CachedAnonymousMethodDelegate1
L_0022: brtrue.s L_0037
L_0024: ldnull 
L_0025: ldftn void Class1::<Test>b__0(valuetype [mscorlib]System.Guid)
L_002b: newobj instance void [mscorlib]System.Action`1<valuetype [mscorlib]System.Guid>::.ctor(object, native int)
L_0030: stsfld class [mscorlib]System.Action`1<valuetype [mscorlib]System.Guid> Class1::CS$<>9__CachedAnonymousMethodDelegate1
L_0035: br.s L_0037
L_0037: ldsfld class [mscorlib]System.Action`1<valuetype [mscorlib]System.Guid> Class1::CS$<>9__CachedAnonymousMethodDelegate1
L_003c: call void Class1::Method1<valuetype [mscorlib]System.Guid, class BECustomer>(string, class [mscorlib]System.Action`1<!!0>)
```

Comment: so is there any sort of actual performance difference between the lambda and the method group? I can see 5 more lines of IL, but what kind of real world difference are we talking? a couple ticks on really large data sets?

Comment: The worst case would be calling your `Method1` for each item in a large set - a new instance of the anonymous class would be created on each iteration. That said, it's unlikely using a lambda instead of method group will measurably impact your app. Only measuring can tell you for sure though.

Comment: The lambda expression generates more code but according to [this post](http://vibrantcode.com/2013/02/19/lambdas-vs-method-groups/), the lambda expression is actually a little faster than the method group and uses less memory because "the Method Group version allocates a new object every single time it is run whereas the lambda version uses an instance (or static, as necessary) field to cache the delegate."

Comment: As of [C#11](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-11#improved-method-group-conversion-to-delegate), using method group will create a new instance of delegate object and reuse it, so there's no extra unnecessary allocation anymore

Answer (score 1):

Where your `Method1<Guid, BECustomer>` accepts a `Func<Guid, BECustomer>` argument, `Func<Guid, BECustomer>` is synonymous with:

```
public delegate BECustomer Func(Guid arg);
```

In fact, all a `Func` is is a generic delegate:

```
public delegate TResult Func<T, TResult>(T arg);
```

The compiler can analyse your code and determine that your `Func<Guid, BECustomer>` is compatible with the method group for `Facade.Customers.GetSingle` because the method signature matches the delegate signature.

This is syntactic sugar and is another example of the compiler doing the grunt work for you.