# Context binding in C# and how it works

Tags: c#, oop, delegates

I'm new to the C#, and I get acquainted with delegates. I have this test code:

```
internal class Class1
  {
    string name = "John";
    int age = 19;
        
    public void printName() => Console.WriteLine(this.name + " " + this.age);
  }
        
internal class Class2
  {
    public delegate void speaker();
    private speaker? _myDelegate;
    public void addDelegate(speaker deleg) => _myDelegate = deleg;
        
    public void wrapper()
    {
      Console.WriteLine("This is a message from Class2 \n");
      _myDelegate.Invoke();
    }
  }
    
Class1 A = new Class1();
Class2 B = new Class2();
B.addDelegate(A.printName);
B.wrapper();
```

The question is how the method keeps access to all data fields (scope) from first class through a delegate?

Comment: As long as `Class1 A` exists, `B` will be able to call its `printName` method. And you declared  `A` and `B` at the same scope, so it is no problem.

Comment: @Cleptus Even if `A` would go out of scope, the delegate still has a reference to the object so it will live as long as `B` does.

Comment: @KlausGütter Thanks. Is there any source where exactly described delegate and what he stores (besides source code)?

Comment: I think is not looking for delegates information, but for reference types. The garbage collector does not dispose the objects that are referenced/used

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13603795/using-delegates-in-c-sharp

Comment: @KlausGütter oh, yeah, I see, I unknowingly made the correct implementation through a function, so it works as intended. And I didn't get the error from the post you sent (I was expecting to get this kind of errors and was surprised when didn't see it). Now I understand how it works, thanks.